# Where to find open source 3d charts available?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, flex4

I am looking for opensource or unlicensed 3D charts.

if you have some link please share them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Google Charts?

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: i saw this link, could not found SWC(library) for downloand

Comment: @flex your question is tagging php, js and flash results. This is a HTML lib. Please update your question if you are looking only for AS3 / Flash libs.

Answer (score 1):

The only real open source(MIT license) 3D charts that I know of are these two

https://github.com/bkuzmic/raphael-charts-plugin 
https://github.com/PuffyCoffee/3D-Pie-chart

The first one offers both a pie & bar option. The author is still actively working on it so it should improve over time.

There are other 3D charting tools that claim to be "free" and "open source". But their license is extremely restrictive. Basically, they only allow you to use their tool for free only if you use it for a personal websites with no ads and zero commercial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add). IBM, NASA, Siemens and others use it according to their Web site. It's pure JavaScript. I searched the Web quite a while for it. I am not quite sure if 3D charts are possible, however it should serve most needs.

Comment: It looks like it is a commercial product??

Answer (score 0):

Not really 3D, but you could use Flex SDK's data charts:  http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/charts/

I don't recall what the status is on the data vis components - they weren't able to open them when they released the rest of the SDK, and I can't find anything on their current status.

I still have yet to come across any other package, Open Source or not, JS or Flash, that will do log-log plots as easily as I could with Flex Charting - some will do y axis, but not x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a little late to the party perhaps - but RGraph can be used under the MIT license and produces some nice 3D charts:

http://www.rgraph.net/docs/3d-javascript-charts.html